# Android to arduino- best board option for wireless

Tags: arduino, wireless, android

I'm a novice arduino hacker. I need to connect a hacked Android to an arduino wirelessly but unclear as to which option is best. I've read about the Mega ADK and it is my understanding that a regular board (uno?) can be used with a wireless bluetooth dongle.

What is the best and easiest way to connect to an arduino wirelessly?

Comment: I have modified the question, could you please review the "too broad"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the [Mega ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK), It is quite good, being specifically designed for Android projects, but it is not wireless. If you need wireless, it could be worth taking a look at the [Arduino BT](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBT). You would have to do the Android app separately, but once you made that, the BT has built-in bluetooth and useful libraries that make connecting easy. Your other option would be a bluetooth shield, of which there are plenty, though none of them are official. There are also [WiFi](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) and [NFC](http://www.adafruit.com/products/789) shields but they are more complicated. Possibly still worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Two main options. Wifi (or ethernet through a wifi router), or Bluetooth. And not with a regular usb bluetooth dongle. You need a bluetooth module, typically Serial/Uart to Bluetooth.

The third option is a computer (or hacked router) with a serial connection to the arduino, and a program to communicate via wifi with the Android device. This adds an extra layer of complications.